# Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Source code exceeds max accepted (500k chars) length

Tags: solidity, blockchain, etherscan, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I deployed a contract through a factory contract, now when I try to verify it through hardhat, it throws error below.

```
Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Source code exceeds max accepted (500k chars) length
```

Problem is similar to this this [issue](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/2475) but I have not tried deploying without factory and then verify it through hardhat.

Can anyone help me how can I verify contract now?